# Need to fix my checkboxes: to change states in one click instead of two clicks. Swift 3, IOS

Tags: ios, checkbox, swift3

I have multiple checkboxes that work decently. 
The way it works is that there's two images (an image of a checked box OR an image of an unchecked box) that show up or disappear into my button, based on clicking that button.

For some reason when it's the first time I click a checkbox it works perfectly (changes its state to: checked or unchecked - when clicked once), but when i go to try a second, third, or fourth (etc.) checkbox, it requires two clicks to change its state (checked/unchecked).

This is annoying and confusing to the user. Is there any way around this?

Here are my last 3 checkboxes:

```
/////Checkboxes

@IBOutlet weak var Box49: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var Box50: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var Box51: UIButton!



var BoxON = UIImage(named: "CheckBox")
var BoxOFF = UIImage(named:"UnCheckBox")

var isBoxClicked: Bool!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    isBoxClicked = false
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func Box49(_ sender: Any) {

    if isBoxClicked == true{
        isBoxClicked = false
    }else{
        isBoxClicked = true
    }
    if isBoxClicked == true{
        Box49.setImage(BoxON, for: UIControlState.normal)

    }else{
        Box49.setImage(BoxOFF, for: UIControlState.normal)
    }
}


@IBAction func Box50(_ sender: Any) {

    if isBoxClicked == true{
        isBoxClicked = false
    }else{
        isBoxClicked = true
    }
    if isBoxClicked == true{
        Box50.setImage(BoxON, for: UIControlState.normal)

    }else{
        Box50.setImage(BoxOFF, for: UIControlState.normal)
    }
}


@IBAction func Box51(_ sender: Any) {

    if isBoxClicked == true{
        isBoxClicked = false
    }else{
        isBoxClicked = true
    }
    if isBoxClicked == true{
        Box51.setImage(BoxON, for: UIControlState.normal)

    }else{
        Box51.setImage(BoxOFF, for: UIControlState.normal)
    }
}
```

Thanks, Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are using same instance property `isBoxClicked` with all button instead of that you need to set the image to all button for both state normal and selected and then in your button action simply changed its selected state.
Also either change your button outlet name or action name because they both are same. So it should be like this.

```
@IBOutlet var box49: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var box50: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var box51: UIButton!


override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

     box49.setImage(BoxOFF, for: .normal)
     box49.setImage(BoxON, for: .selected)

     box50.setImage(BoxOFF, for: .normal)
     box50.setImage(BoxON, for: .selected)

     box51.setImage(BoxOFF, for: .normal)
     box51.setImage(BoxON, for: .selected)
}
```

And now set your button action this way.

```
@IBAction func box49Button(_ sender: Button) {
     sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
}

@IBAction func box50Button(_ sender: Button) {
     sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
}

@IBAction func box51Button(_ sender: Button) {
     sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
}
```

Or you can add single button action and set that action to all three button instead of having three different action for each button like this.

```
@IBAction func boxButton(_ sender: Button) {
     sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
}
```

Comment: how would i write it in full? i keep getting errors. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here

Comment: @DanielG What errors you are getting edit your question with your tried code if possible show the screen shot of errors.

Comment: @DanielG You need to set this image in ViewDidlLoad, check my answer once again you are setting image in `didReceiveMemoryWarning`.

Comment: value of type UIButton has no member set image

Comment: i did in that other post! :)

Comment: @DanielG Check that have you try setting image like my answer means declaring variable of image literal

Comment: @DanielG Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 0):

you are using one instance of `isBoxClicked` variable for all button. You should create an array of `isBoxClicked`. by using array you can check further that which checkbox(`UIButon`) is check an which is unchecked .

```
var isBoxClickedArray:[int] = {0,0}
```

**First create enum for get index of buttons**

```
enum  ButtonIndex{
case Box49
case Box50
}
```

**assign enum value as tag in button**

```
Box49Button.tag = ButtonIndex.Box49.rawValue
Box50Button.tag = ButtonIndex.Box50.rawValue
```

**create one method for get action**

```
 @IBAction func actionType(_ sender: Any) {
        let button = sender as! UIBarButton
        if ( button.tag == ButtonIndex.BOX49.rawValue ){
            print("Box49 button pressed")
            if ( isBoxClicked[ButtonIndex.BOX49.rawValue] == 0 ){
                  print("box49 is unchecked")
                  isBoxClicked[ButtonIndex.BOX49.rawValue] = 1// change  it's value to checked
                  // change image also
            }else{
                // box is checked
                isBoxClicked[ButtonIndex.BOX49.rawValue]  = 0
                // change value in array and image also
            }
        }else{
            print("Box50 button pressed")
        }
    }
```

**update**

declare array in viewcontroller. and assign tag on button in viewdidload or cellforrowAtindexpath if you are using tableview. for enum declare them like this

```
import UIKit
enum indexs : Int{
    case first
    case second
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
```

Comment: i can't seem to write it all together. I'm a little lost. how would you get the expected declaration (for your var) or the expected expression (for your enum)?